# How to use nodejs to processing cvs

Tags: node.js, database, csv

I wonder how to processing the following cvs efficiently using nodejs, I have large dataset so I prefer createReadStream, but dataset look like this, I want to sum the amount if the open and close are the same time

```
amount,         open,          close
100,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
200,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
300,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
200,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-28 13:19:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
```

output csv would be

```
600,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
300,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-28 13:19:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd love to help you, but we can't just tell you how to do something. We need to see what code you already have, what you have tried, and what issues you are seeing. You can read about [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on the StackOverflow help docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the excellent csv-parse library, I wouldn't ever recommend rolling your own csv parsing solution.

In this example we parse and sum as we go.

The last record needs special treatment as shown!

**testfile.csv**

```
amount,open,close
100,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
200,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
300,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
200,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-28 13:19:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
```

**example.js**

```
const parse = require('csv-parse');
const transform = require('stream-transform');
const fs = require('fs');

let input = fs.createReadStream('testfile.csv');
let outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('outfile.csv');

function sumRecords(cache) {
    let first = cache[0];
    return cache.reduce((acc,rec) => {
       acc[0] += Number(rec[0]);
       return acc;
    }, [0, first[1], first[2]]);
}

// Cache of same records.
records = [];
var parser = parse({delimiter: ','})
var transformer = transform((record, callback) => {

    // Skip header.. 
    if (record[0] == 'amount') {
        callback(null, record.join(',') + '\n');
        return;
    }

    if (records.length != 0) {
        let firstRecord = records[0];
        if (firstRecord[1] != record[1] || firstRecord[2] != record[2]) {
            // Sum up records.
            let outputRecord = sumRecords(records);
            callback(null, outputRecord.join(',') + '\n');
            records = []; // Clear our cache.
        }
    }
    records.push(record);
});

input.pipe(parser).pipe(transformer).pipe(outputStream);

// Write any remaining records to file.
setTimeout(() => {
    fs.appendFile('outfile.csv', sumRecords(records).join(','), () => {});
}, 1000);
```

We get an output that looks like this:

**outfile.csv**

```
amount,open,close
600,2017-08-28 13:18:46,2017-08-30 11:18:01
300,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-28 13:19:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
100,2017-08-30 03:32:24,2017-08-30 11:18:01
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the perfect solution for this. I'm writing a rough algorithm for you.

> Steps

1. Split the csv data with '\n' --> Convert it to array
2. Each item in array is assigned to csvLineObj.
3. Now you can access each line differently.

```js
var aTempArray=[];

for(will run from 0 to length of CSV){  

  var trArr= csvLineObj.split(","); 
  // Will return an array
  
  if(trArr[1]===trArr[2]){ aTempArray.psuh(csvLineObj); 
  // You have the array of results in aTempArray
  
}

aTempArray.concat("\n"); ---> You have the desired result
```